# Keycloak - Adding an Additional Step to Login

Tags: keycloak

I have a situation where during login, after a user has entered their username/password, they would get transferred to an additional page where they would have to enter an additional field (or select something from a select box)

Today, I use a simple session id over a cookie. When a user enters their credentials I create a session, and after they had entered the field in the additional page, I update the session.

I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve something like that in Keycloak. I would also like to include that additional field in the token.

I guess the obvious way would be to keep my login frontend as it is now and use the direct credentials grant API that Keycloak provides, but I would rather avoid that.

Please advise.

Clarifications: Each user in the system can belong to multiple organizations. That additional field corresponds to the organization that the user logs in to. All applications that interact with the token have to be aware of that organization field

Comment: How many applications (by application i mean keycloak OIDC client) would use data from you additional post-auth step? If this data should be used only by specific client its better to move this logic to dedicated app otherwise its could be added to Keycloak as SPI extension. Please give a little more details about feature that you require

Comment: @solveMe Thank you for answering. I've updated the question. Basically, this additional field could be used by any client/application that interacts with the token so I believe it has to be part of the authentication process in Keycloak. I've read about SPI extensions, in fact, I'm trying to create one right now for `UserStorageProvider` (since the users of the systems are stored in an external database). Can you provide some reading/watching material regarding creating an SPI for my purpose?

Comment: Did i understand correctly that user can belong to multiple companies and on each login he can switch to another company? This is a quite weird scenario. If I am wrong and user constantly has one-to-one binding with some company, you are on right direction with USP implementation. You can expose company binding as UserModel attribute, and then use this attribute value in OIDC User Attribute mapper to add company to access/refresh tokens.

Comment: @solveMe users usually have one to one mapping, but some can have one to many (one users can belong to many companies). In that case, I would like to allow the user to select the company they want to log in with, after they've entered username/password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirements i would suggest following:

1. Continue with UserStorageProvider implementation. Refer to following [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi). Your implementation should also provide list of available companies for every user. You can expose this list as an UserModel attribute.
2. Implement custom required action (components like that runs after successfully passed credential challenges) that will get list of available companies from UserModel object of authenticated user. Offer this list to user as separate login form, so after user submits his choice it will be persisted in user session note. As example check out implementation for [UpdateUserLocaleAction](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/12.0.2/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/requiredactions/UpdateUserLocaleAction.java) and javadoc for [RequiredActionProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/12.0.2/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/RequiredActionProvider.java). Here is example of logic for storing selected company:

   ```
   @Override
   public void requiredActionChallenge(RequiredActionContext context) {
       List<String> availableCompanies = context.getUser().getAttribute("companies");
       ... // form rendering
   }

   @Override
   public void processAction(RequiredActionContext context) {
       String company = context.getHttpRequest().getFormParameters().getFirst("selected_company");
       context.getAuthenticationSession().setUserSessionNote("company", company);
   }
   ```
3. Add UserSessionNote oidc mapper to required client (or to shared client scope), so it will extract 'company' note saved by required action implementation from step 2
4. ???
5. Profit

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and update how it went